# Unity IoC Invalid Operation when change then lifetime manager in RegisterType

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-interception

I have this configuration for my IoC with Unity in my MVC 4 project.

```
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, ConstructionRepositoryContext>("ConstructionRepositoryContext", new TransientLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, GeneralRepositoryContext>("GeneralRepositoryContext", new TransientLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(
    "ConstructionUnitOfWork",
    new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IDbContext>("ConstructionRepositoryContext")));

container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(
    "GeneralUnitOfWork",
    new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IDbContext>("GeneralRepositoryContext")));
```

When I change `TransientLifetimeManager` by `PerRequestLifetimeManager` or something else, the following exception happen:

(Error in line 101)

```
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Line 99:  new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IDbContext>("ConstructionRepositoryContext")));
Line 100:
Line 101: container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(
Line 102:   "GeneralUnitOfWork",
Line 103:   new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IDbContext>("GeneralRepositoryContext")));
```

Comment: how are you resolving the container for `IUnitofWork`?

Comment: looks like I was mistaken, `InjectionConstructor` is not deprecated. Deleted the previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is probably thrown at this line:

```
container.Resolve<IDbContext>("ConstructionRepositoryContext"))
```

This line is problematic, at the time when unity really resolves an `IUnitOfWork` (which could be another request), the `IDbContext` object resolved here has been destroyed.

Try:

```
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(
    "ConstructionUnitOfWork",
    new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IDbContext>("ConstructionRepositoryContext")));
```

This tells the container that:

When resolving the `UnitOfWork` with named `"ConstructionUnitOfWork"`, use the constructor that takes a single `IDbContext` parameter, and when resolving that parameter, resolve using the name `"ConstructionRepositoryContext"`